# Why the ampersands in this jQueryfunction

Tags: jquery

I'm looking at some code for a shoutbox at [yensdesigns](http://yensdesign.com/2009/01/create-a-shoutbox-using-php-and-ajax-jquery/), and in this function it's checking to make sure the form fields are complete. What's with all the ampersands? Is that important? I'm a newbie/hobbyist, don't really get what he's doing with that?

```
//check if all fields are filled  
function checkForm(){  
    if(inputUser.attr("value") &amp;amp;amp;amp;amp;amp;&amp;amp;amp;amp;amp;amp; inputMessage.attr("value"))  
        return true;  
    else  
        return false;  
}
```

Is it the same if I write

```
  //check if all fields are filled  
    function checkForm(){  
        if(inputUser.attr("value"); inputMessage.attr("value"))  
            return true;  
        else  
            return false;  
    }
```

Comment: What are you trying to do? Neither are correct if-statements.

Comment: It looks like the original code was `if (inputUser.attr("value") && inputMessage.attr("value"))`, but that got escaped into oblivion.

Comment: @Frédéric Hamidi: "escaped into oblivion" makes me feel pity for those ampersands :(

Answer (score 4, accepted):

It's an error in the function (and the guide, shame on them). The correct one would be:

```
function checkForm(){  
    if(inputUser.attr("value") && inputMessage.attr("value"))  
        return true;  
    else  
        return false;  
}
```

Answer (score 4):

To me it looks like someone HTML encoded `&&` 6 times.  Not sure why it would have happened but I've seen similar stuff before when characters were HTML encoded more than once.

Are you sure it works with your semicolon seperated example?  I can't even get it to run:

http://jsfiddle.net/WSdkG/2/

If you uncomment the first example nothing happens.  Once you comment it out you get the expected functionality.

Answer (score 2):

Try this instead:

```
function checkForm(){  
    if(inputUser.attr("value") && inputMessage.attr("value"))  
        return true;  
    else  
        return false;  
}
```

Or this if you want to make it short:

```
function checkForm(){  
    return (inputUser.attr("value") && inputMessage.attr("value")); 
}
```

Comment: You don't need `!= ""` since an empty string evaluates to false in javascript.